# Getting Garbage Output Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a constructor in Java and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but I keep getting garbage outputs.

This is the variable I'm trying to assign values to:

```
private static Employee employee;
```

This is how I'm trying to assign it:

```
employee = new Employee(empType, empFName, empLName, empBDate, empGender, empHireDate, empReleaseDate, empBaseSalary);
```

And here is the class and constructor:

```
public class Employee {

    private String Type;
    private String FName;
    private String LName;
    private Date BDate;
    private String Gender;
    private Date HireDate;
    private Date ReleaseDate;
    private double BaseSalary;


    public Employee(String type, String fname, String lname, String bdate, String gender, String hire, String release, double salary){


        this.Type = type;
        this.FName = fname.toUpperCase();
        this.LName = lname.toUpperCase();      
        this.BDate = new Date(bdate);       
        this.Gender = gender;
        this.HireDate = new Date(hire);
        if (release == "null"){
            this.ReleaseDate = null;
        }
        else if(release != "null"){
            this.ReleaseDate = new Date(release);
        }
        this.BaseSalary = salary;

    }

}
```

When I try to print, just to test it, this is how I'm printing it:

```
System.out.println(employee);
```

And this is what I get every time:

```
Employee@4c264dd8
```

Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You must Override the `toString()` method if you want to print your object in this way. What you see is the default output of toString, the type and hashcode of an object.

Comment: that's not garbage, that's the identity hashcode of the object

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+override+tostring&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS562US562&oq=java+override+tostring&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2986j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) a google search for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java doesn't know anything about how you want an object printed unless you tell it what to do by implementing `toString()`. If you don't, it will default to [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) to get a string representation of your object. `Object.toString()` returns

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

which explains the output you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you print Object in Java ,it will print class Name with Hexadecimal value.

If you want your own thing you have to override toString().

```
public void toString()
{
   //print here  this.Type +":"+   this.FName  for fields you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Java Object comes with a toString() method. You will have to override it to get the desired output.I believe hashCode of the object (memory address) is being printed!

Answer (score 0):

From the Object.toString() docs:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Therefore, you must provide your own toString method by doing this:

```
@Override
```

> public void toString(){ return myString; }